# Javascript `onError` is not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, http, http-status-code-404

Please have a look at the below code

```
function longSentenceSpeak(text)
{
    var string = text.trim().split(" ").join("+");
    var finalString = string.replace(";",",")
    var url = "http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+finalString;
    var url2 = "http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=sp&q="+finalString;

    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

    var source = document.getElementById('source');
    source.src=url;

    audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
    audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away
}
```

Below is my HTML

TODO supply a title

```
    <script src="scripts/TTS.js"></script>
    <script>
       function longText()
       {
           longSentenceSpeak("hello world ");
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio">
        <source id="source" src="" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>

    <div><button onclick="longText()">Click me</button></div>
</body>
```

However this sometimes gives the below error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (12:49:15:455 | error, network)
  at http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello
```

What I want to do is, if this error occurred, I want to use `var url2` instead of `var url` in `function longSentenceSpeak(text)`. how can I do this?

**update**

I tried the below, no good

```
function longSentenceSpeak(text)
        {
            var string = text.trim().split(" ").join("+");
            var finalString = string.replace(";",",")
            var url = "http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+finalString;
            var url2 = "http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=sp&q="+finalString;

            var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

            var source = document.getElementById('source');
            source.src=url;

            audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
            audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away

        audio.onerror = function()
        {
            var url2 = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+text;

            var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

            var source = document.getElementById('source');
            source.src = url2;

            audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
            audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away
        };
        }
```

Comment: `audio.onerror = function() { swap url and try again }`

Comment: adeneo is saying when an error occurs, you should just use the same code using the other URL. You should be able to do that easily, given you've already made this code yourself.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: OK, previously all the tutorials I tried applied this `onerror` thing in html tag it self, that is what I GOT CONFUSED.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: No good in that as well. I have made an update, pls take a look.

Comment: @adeneo: No good in that as well. I have made an update, please take a look.